# React-waypoint topOffset example code or how to use in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sticky, scrolltop, waypoint

Can any one please tell me or send me sample code for how to write the code for topOffset in react-waypoint please.

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple, you just need to add it as a prop `< Waypoint topOffset="50px" />`

For instance, if your app has a 50px fixed header, then you may want to specify topOffset='50px', so that the onEnter callback is called when waypoints scroll into view from beneath the header. You can check the documentation [here](https://github.com/civiccc/react-waypoint#example-usage)

I coded a simple example that might help in case you need it

https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-react-waypoint-mhukn?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score -1):

I have some example code that does sticky top.
You can set the offset.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-ellis-gtvbl?file=/src/header.jsx